# NHibernate: How to fetch an object without its child collections?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fetch, fetching-strategy

My objects of type Object1 contain List Children1 property.
I would love to get these objects without children.

Seems like detachedCriteria.SetFetchMode ("Children1", FetchMode.Lazy) should be the thing,
but apparently it's not :(
I tried getting the data in using (new SessionScope()) and setting null to .Children1 but it didn't succeed (the data was already fetched).

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I "solved" the problem after few days of asking the question, but forgot to write here about it.
Having set Lazy=true in the HasMany mapping:
1) When I want eager behaviour I set criteria.SetFetchMode ("Children1", FetchMode.Eager)
2) When I want lazy  behaviour I set criteria.SetFetchMode ("Children1", FetchMode.Lazy) and just after then I FindAll (criteria) my objects I set null to the Children1 List property.

I'm not sure all of these tricks are necessary, but I don't care anymore.

Answer (score 0):

When you map the collection, are you specifying not to use lazy loading? Try specifying lazy loading at this point.

Comment: I did not specify anything, so default values apply, however I don't know what is a default value.
BTW, problem is "solved". I'll add a comment in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem in our current solution and setting Lazy in the mapping didn't work. We had to set default-lazy to true and suddenly it worked.

This would work best if all relations should be lazy by default.

Comment: Ok, I've set Lazy=true on the HasMany attribute and now it works,
but in other (more frequent) use-cases I need eager loading...
I would prefer to have eager loading by default and lazy on demand,
but if that's too complicated... I'll try fixing those other use-cases (now I get LazyInitializationException ... failed to lazily initialize a collection of role ... no session or session was closed)

Comment: You get that exception because your session has been closed, like the message says. You need to inject your session into your repository/dataaccess class and control the session lifetime from the outside.

You'd want the session to last the entire request lifetime, especially if you have lazy loading.

We use a UnitOfWork attribute on our mvc controllers to initiate and close down a session, and if any nhibernate exceptions are thrown, it is cought and session is rolled back

Answer (score 0):

When using the ICriteria API to retrieve your entities, you can specify (override) the fetchmode that has to be used for the associations:

```
ICriteria crit = session.CreateCriteria (typeof(MyEntity));
crit.SetFetchMode ("someAssociationPath", FetchMode.Lazy);
```

Comment: I've tried that. Have you actually read my question? ;)
BTW, problem is "solved". I'll add a comment in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are using one-to-one mapping. In this case lazy loading will not work by design. If it's so please check [this article](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/lazy-loaded-one-to-one-with-nhibernate.aspx). Otherwise please provide a bit more code and mappings.

Comment: Why does it seem to you as a one-to-one mapping? when Object1 has List<Children1> I think it is clear that it is at least one-to-many.
BTW, problem is "solved". I'll add a comment in a few minutes.

Comment: @wysek, you didn't provided any code so I just assumed the most likelihood reason from my point of view. Sorry, I'm not well at mind reading.